# Research on independent / freelance sound designers

Tags: business, career-advice, research, small, indie

Hi all,

I'm in the process of setting myself up as a sole trader for sound design services in the south east of England. I've been freelancing for a couple of years and operate a relatively humble setup designed for relatively small-scale projects but have decided recently to establish myself as a small business. My goal is to offer a complete sound design service for those with modest post budgets (independent directors, small video production houses, corporate film-makers, etc.). I'm aiming to keep the rates reasonable by negating the need for overly-elaborate studio complexes and doing the majority of the work from my own residence.

My question to everyone is: In order to start the market research elements of my business plan, are there are any sound designers out there that operate on a similar basis either nationally or internationally? If so, is there any way I can ask a few questions about the operational considerations such a business must take into account (rates of pay, marketing approach, legal factors)?

I would really appreciate any help at all. It's proving very difficult to research identical business models compared to the massive post-houses that top the search rankings. I have a suspicion it's a need-to-know-basis and I really need to know!

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in NZ almost all the sound editors are freelance... but I doubt thats any help with your questions, as they are region & work specific... Rates of pay depends on the total budget of the project and your experience/what you bring to the project. Business advice is best asked of an accountant and/or lawyer... The best marketing happens via word of mouth - be helpful, do lots of good work <- directors and producers notice...

Comment: Thanks for your reply, Tim. I guess the word "business" is a bit of a misnomer in this context. I'm using the term as a way of encapsulating what I do and how it makes money to bank managers and governmental departments. I've always had a little bit of trouble dealing with the term "competitors" and having to profile others. Alas, that's what they want in my business plan.

In reality, a director is more likely to go with someone they've had good results from in the past and I can fully understand that. I guess I'll have another go at getting that across to my investors!